# Подскажите как мне в моем html файле переписать удаление что бы кнопка delet работала с @DeleteMapping

Tags: java, spring

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    private final UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
    private final RoleService roleService;
    private PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public AdminController(UserServiceImpl userDetailServiceImpl, RoleService roleService, PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userServiceImpl = userDetailServiceImpl;
        this.roleService = roleService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String getAllUsers(Model model) {
        List<Role> roles = roleService.findAllRoles();
        model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("users", userServiceImpl.getAllUsers());
        return "admin";
    }
    @GetMapping("/addUser")
    public String registrUser(Model model) {
        List<Role> roles = roleService.findAllRoles();
        model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "addUser";
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public String listUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userServiceImpl.createUser(user);

        return "redirect:/admin";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/users/remove/{id}")
    public String deletUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        userServiceImpl.removeUser(id);
        return "redirect:/admin";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/edit/{id}")
    public String editPage(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        List<Role> roles = roleService.findAllRoles();
        model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
        model.addAttribute("user", userServiceImpl.findUserById(id));
        return "edit";
    }
    @PatchMapping("/users/{id}")
    public String editUser (@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userServiceImpl.updateUser(user);

        return "redirect:/admin";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Users</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Список пользователей</h1>
  <h3><a th:href="@{/admin/addUser}">Регистрация</a></h3>
  <br/>
  <th:if test="${!empty users}">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>username</th>
        <th>password</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>e-mail</th>
        <th>role</th>
        <th>action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr th:each="user: ${users}">
        <td th:text="${user.getId()}">id</td>
        <td th:text="${user.getUsername()}">id</td>
        <td th:text="${user.getPassword()}">id</td>
        <td th:text="${user.getName()}">name</td>
        <td th:text="${user.getAge()}">age</td>
        <td th:text="${user.getEmail()}">e-mail</td>
        <td th:text="${user.getRolesString()}">role</td>
        <td>
          <a th:href="@{/admin/users/edit/{id}(id=${user.getId()})}">Edit</a>
          <a th:href="@{/admin/users/remove/{id}(id=${user.getId()})}">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </th:if>


  <h3><a th:href="@{/logout}">Выйти из учетной записи</a></h3>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод thymeleaf который добавит в получившийся html скрытое поле со значением delete, которое в свою очередь подхватит spring mvc. Подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256051/delete-or-put-methods-in-thymeleaf)

Comment: спасибо , очень помогло